# Application of VBA control arrays in Access

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I need to understand how I can relate the array of controls I `dim` in VBA code with the related form and the syntax etc. needed in the code to manipulate the array.

I'm wanting to populate and present an array of textboxes with strings that have been constructed as a result of processing data in a series of tables.

As an initial test, I've tried the following code. I've not yet thought of any way I might attempt to create an array on the surface of a form.

I have several text books on VBA but none of them seem to have anything to say on this.

Can anyone throw any light on this or recommend a more advanced text book?

```
Dim mytext(20) As TextBox
Dim x As Long
For x = 0 To 19
    mytext(x).Value = str(x)
Next x
```

This results in an error at line 4:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: For starters, try adding this to the top of your module: **Option Base 0**. And if not mistaken , You'll still be able to reference **mytext(20).Value**. Yeah I know, doesn't make all that much sense.

Comment: @flaZer `mytext(20) as TextBox`is the same as`mytext(0 to 20) as TextBox`if`Option Base 0`(default) as you just define the upper bound, not the size

Answer (score 1):

How are you populating your array of Textboxes?

Since Textboxes are objects, you'll need to use `Set`, e.g.:

```
Dim mytext(20) As TextBox
Set mytext(0) = Text0
Set mytext(1) = Text2
Set mytext(2) = Text4
Set mytext(3) = Text6
...
```

---

Aside, [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) is a built-in function in VBA, it should not be used as the name of a 
variable.